# Azure Deployment Failed - not enough free threads in the ThreadPool

Tags: deployment, azure, threadpool

I was deploying an Azure instance using Visual Studio (2010) and i get this:

```
06:20:05 - Preparing deployment for **** with Subscription ID: ****...
06:20:05 - Connecting...
06:20:06 - Verifying storage account '****'...
06:20:07 - Uploading Package...
06:20:38 - There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation.
06:20:38 - Deployment failed
```

I tried again and it worked, but this has got me a bit worried...

Do I have a threading issue in my instance, is it in Visual Studio or some management system on Azure?

I can't find a single mention of this anywhere and it does seem a bit nonsensical; how can there not be enough threads to replace an instance?

I'm using parallels for a few cross federation lookups, but the system isn't even in production yet - the number of users can be counted on one hand - And even if it were, there presently is no more than one member in any federation... 
I can't see any reason why there would be any problems - but i would very much like to know what on earth would cause this.

It's a single small compute instance with a web role and a worker role - latest Azure version and .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen anything like this before, but it appears to me that it is local to your development machine.

When you deploy from Visual Studio the first step is to copy the deployment files to your Azure storage account. You can see this is what was being done based on the message right before the notification of failure (06:20:07 - Uploading Package...'). This is happening as part of the push of the files to Azure storage and has nothing to do with your Azure project or any of the role size/definition.

I would not be concerned from an Azure perspective here.

Hope this helps some!

Comment: Second this. Your deployment is failing on upload, not deployment to instances. Hence it is your computer having the issues or a connection fault to your Azure storage account.

Comment: I have seen this before when I have many windows open and Visual Studio "locks up" temporarily.  I have not seen this error in a while though.

Comment: Alright i'll assume it's innocuous for now. I will follow up if there turns out to be more to it. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: When I have this issue on my dev machine first of all I kill the processes related to Azure and try to publish again. If it fails again then I close Visual Studio and start again. It's a dirty solution but it works!